# Using MSYS2, QT and MinGW 64

Tags: qt, qt-creator, msys2

**I have installed MSYS2 / QT / MinGW64.**
My question is about QT Source Code version. How can I distinguish which version is downloaded using MSYS2 CLI? I need the commercial version of code.

My problem is:
**Q:** How can I know if I'm on a commercial version or opensource version? How distinguish? 
**Q:** Have I on opensource version? It's possible add a license on it programatically?
Obs: I know that I can download the qt source code and compile everything again but that takes a lot of work.

Comment: are you looking for `qmake --version` ?

Comment: That only gives me the version, In my case is 5.10.1. But how to know if it's free or commercial?

Comment: If you downloaded it through msys pacman you can assume it's the opensource version. I think you can run the maintenanceTool.exe and provide your credentials

Comment: @Amfasis that should be perfect but I didn't have such tool, only for MSYS2, in QT directory I haven't. Should I install it? How could work?

Comment: In that case I think you should download the commercial version yourself from the website (after logging in) and setup your Qt creator to use that installation (create your own kit and point to the proper location of compiler&debugger)

Comment: @Amfasis that is the point which I'd like to avoid. It's not only download the commercial version, I need to download the _source code_ and compile with 64 bit compiler because official QT installation on Windows only supports 32-bit code with GCC toolkit. as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: sorry, missed that. And then I'm out of ideas